# Phpstorm line numbers column width

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

The numbers column is very wide, and this is bothers me. I want to open more workspaces. Therefore I want it to be narrow. How do I do this?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: How many lines are they in your file?

Comment: There are only 60 lines.

Comment: This litle thing bothers me too :-(

Answer (score 11):

I use PHPStorm Version 2017.1.4.  In this version there is an option to hide gutter icons, which reduces the line number column width.  Even if there are no gutter icons visible, the space is still allocated.  If you don't need these icons, you can choose to hide them in the settings and the column width will be reduced.

Navigate in settings to: Editor > General > Gutter Icons
Uncheck: "Show Gutter Icons"

Before Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGRjH.jpg
After Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4u4F.jpg

Answer (score 5):

It seems that is not possible because the place is used by others functionality of PHPStorm. Others questions on StakOverflow deal with disable this other functionality on this place but is not possible too.

We have nothing action on this place of PHPStorm. Use or no functionality.

You can try to open an issue on jetBrains website...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure "editor.distraction.free.mode" isn't enabled in Registry. Otherwise this is a bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-148002