# PhpStorm, remove line numbers spacing

Tags: phpstorm

[image]

Does any know how to remove the spacing after the line numbers in PhpStorm (v10)

When you have 2 or 3 vertical columns it is just a waste of real estate!

Comment: You cannot (I have found no such setting). Thing is: depending on a file type that space is used for some additional elements (e.g. color box in CSS and alike; links to parent/overridden methods in PHP etc) + enough space to place breakpoints/bookmarks etc (in previous versions it was sometimes difficult to do using mouse from first attempt). There is actually a hidden setting to hide all additional icons from gutter .. but it does not remove that extra space...

Comment: You can view my response for the same question here : [Issue stakoverflow PHPStorm wide column line number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35114604/phpstorm-line-numbers-column-width/35126266#35126266)

Answer (score 6):

You can disable "gutter icons" in the settings (I'm running PhpStorm 2016.3)

This removes all vertical spacing from the right of the line numbers.

[image: Settings Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

As darkomen said PhpStorm use this space for various functionalities:

[image]

For example with the Symfony2 plugin, you have icons to navigate to services classes or Twig templates. You also have a bracket that shows you the "current context" of where your cursor is located.

But indeed, you seem to have more space than my setup, perhaps you should try to change the font used for these columns numbers.